# How to inject dependencies into Yves controller?

Tags: spryker

I know that an instance of `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`  can be injected into Yves controller action method. I know also that a path parameter can be also injected into controller action method. Is there a way to use constructor- or method-injection for the services needed in controller? Or using factory is the only way to get required dependencies into Yves controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that using factory is the correct way for it. And it won't become problematic in future.

Any other option might become `hack` that will make Spryker upgrade problematic and time consuming.